# Sending data from a web form to whatsapp

Tags: javascript, html, whatsapp

I am creating a loan calculator as on [this site](http://gyrofacil.com.br/).

After choosing the total loan and monthly fees you fill out a form with name, phone, and email. Then the user will be directed to whatsapp. What I want is to capture the loan amount + monthly fees + name + phone + email and send it to whatsapp like this screen:

[whatsapp + data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNIxZ.png)

I have created this form with the calculator options and the user input data

```html
<form action="..\contato_enviar.php" method="post">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="value-range-total">
      <span>R$</span>
      <span id="slidernumber">3000</span>
    </div>
    <input
      type="range"
      name="valor"
      min="1000"
      step="500"
      max="10000"
      value="3000"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <span class="value-range">R$ 1mil</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <span class="value-range text-right">R$ 10mil</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <h2 class="title-form">Em quantas parcelas?</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 p-5">
      <!--<button class="button-line">6x</button>-->
      <label for="6x" id="l6x" class="lblcheck">6x</label>
      <input
        type="radio"
        id="6x"
        name="parcelas"
        value="6x"
        placeholder="6x"
        class="ipt-check"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 p-5">
      <!--<button class="button-line">12x</button>-->
      <label for="12x" id="l12x" class="lblcheck active">12x</label>
      <input
        type="radio"
        id="12x"
        name="parcelas"
        checked
        value="12x"
        placeholder="6x"
        class="ipt-check"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 p-5">
      <!--<button class="button-line active">18x</button>-->
      <label for="18x" id="l18x" class="lblcheck">18x</label>
      <input
        type="radio"
        id="18x"
        name="parcelas"
        value="18x"
        placeholder="6x"
        class="ipt-check"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 p-5">
      <!--<button class="button-line">24x</button>-->
      <label for="24x" id="l24x" class="lblcheck">24x</label>
      <input
        type="radio"
        id="24x"
        name="parcelas"
        value="24x"
        placeholder="6x"
        class="ipt-check"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 p-5">
      <!--<button class="button-line">36x</button>-->
      <label for="36x" id="l36x" class="lblcheck">36x</label>
      <input
        type="radio"
        id="36x"
        name="parcelas"
        value="36x"
        placeholder="6x"
        class="ipt-check"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 p-5">
      <!--<button class="button-line">48x</button>-->
      <label for="48x" id="l48x" class="lblcheck">
        48x
        <input
          type="radio"
          id="48x"
          name="parcelas"
          value="48x"
          class="ipt-check"
        />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <h3 class="second-title-form">Parcelas a partir de:</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <h4 class="title-form total-form">
          R$
          <span id="valparc">357,83</span>
          <span class="ast">*</span>
        </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <button class="btn-blue-light" id="finalbtn">SOLICITAR COTAÇÃO</button>
  </div>
  <div class="boxenviar">
    <input
      type="text"
      name="nome"
      placeholder="Nome"
      required
      class="ipt_form"
    />
    <input
      type="text"
      name="tel"
      placeholder="Telefone"
      id="tel"
      required
      class="ipt_form"
    />
    <input
      type="email"
      name="email"
      placeholder="E-mail"
      required
      class="ipt_form"
    />
    <input type="submit" value="solicitar cotação" class="ipt_sbmt" />
  </div>
</form>
```

And this is the "contato_enviar.php" file

```php
<script language='JavaScript'>
  alert('Cotação enviada com sucesso!'); window.location.href =
  '..\api.whatsapp.com\senddfa0.html?phone=5567984536767&amp;text=*Nome:*%20%20*E-mail:*%20%20*Telefone:*%20%20*Valor:*%20R$%20*Num%20de%20Parcelas:*%20%20*Valor%20da%20Parcela:*%20R$nan%20';
</script>
```

Here is the calculator code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $("[type=range]").change(function(){
        var newval= $(this).val();
        $("#slidernumber").text(newval);
          
         if ($('#6x').is(':checked')) {
             var result2 = newval * ((Math.pow((1+0.05), 6)*0.05)/(Math.pow((1+0.05), 6) - 1));
             $('#valparc').text(result2.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
         } else if ($('#12x').is(':checked')) {
             var result2 = newval * ((Math.pow((1+0.06), 12)*0.06)/(Math.pow((1+0.06), 12) - 1));
             $('#valparc').text(result2.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
             
         } else if ($('#18x').is(':checked')) {
             var result2 = newval * ((Math.pow((1+0.06), 18)*0.06)/(Math.pow((1+0.06), 18) - 1));
             $('#valparc').text(result2.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
              
         } else if ($('#24x').is(':checked')) {
             var result2 = newval * ((Math.pow((1+0.06), 24)*0.06)/(Math.pow((1+0.06), 24) - 1));
             $('#valparc').text(result2.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
             
         } else if ($('#36x').is(':checked')) {
             var result2 = newval * ((Math.pow((1+0.06), 36)*0.06)/(Math.pow((1+0.06), 36) - 1));
             $('#valparc').text(result2.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
             
         } else if ($('#48x').is(':checked')) {
             var result2 = newval * ((Math.pow((1+0.06), 48)*0.06)/(Math.pow((1+0.06), 48) - 1));
             $('#valparc').text(result2.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
             
         }
      });
        $('#l6x').click(function(){
            var valnew = $("[type=range]").val();
            $('#l6x').addClass('active');
            $('#l12x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l18x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l24x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l36x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l48x').removeClass('active');
             var result2 = valnew * ((Math.pow((1+0.05), 6)*0.05)/(Math.pow((1+0.05), 6) - 1));
             $('#valparc').text(result2.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
        });  
        $('#l12x').click(function(){
            var valnew = $("[type=range]").val();
            $('#l6x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l12x').addClass('active');
            $('#l18x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l24x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l36x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l48x').removeClass('active');
             var result2 = valnew * ((Math.pow((1+0.06), 12)*0.06)/(Math.pow((1+0.06), 12) - 1));
             $('#valparc').text(result2.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
        });  
        $('#l18x').click(function(){
            var valnew = $("[type=range]").val();
            $('#l6x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l12x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l18x').addClass('active');
            $('#l24x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l36x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l48x').removeClass('active');
             var result2 = valnew * ((Math.pow((1+0.06), 18)*0.06)/(Math.pow((1+0.06), 18) - 1));
             $('#valparc').text(result2.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
        });  
        $('#l24x').click(function(){
            var valnew = $("[type=range]").val();
            $('#l6x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l12x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l18x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l24x').addClass('active');
            $('#l36x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l48x').removeClass('active');
             var result2 = valnew * ((Math.pow((1+0.06), 24)*0.06)/(Math.pow((1+0.06), 24) - 1));
             $('#valparc').text(result2.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
        });  
        $('#l36x').click(function(){
            var valnew = $("[type=range]").val();
            $('#l6x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l12x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l18x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l24x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l36x').addClass('active');
            $('#l48x').removeClass('active');
             var result2 = valnew * ((Math.pow((1+0.06), 36)*0.06)/(Math.pow((1+0.06), 36) - 1));
             $('#valparc').text(result2.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
        });  
        $('#l48x').click(function(){
            var valnew = $("[type=range]").val();
            $('#l6x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l12x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l18x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l24x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l36x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l48x').addClass('active');
             var result2 = valnew * ((Math.pow((1+0.06), 48)*0.06)/(Math.pow((1+0.06), 48) - 1));
             $('#valparc').text(result2.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
        }); 
          $('#finalbtn').click(function(){
             $('.boxenviar').css('display','block'); 
             $('#c-mask').css('display','block'); 
          });
          $('#c-mask').click(function(){
             $('.boxenviar').css('display','none'); 
             $('#c-mask').css('display','none'); 
          });
          
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: so you want to display the user inputted data on submit?

Comment: Yes. When the page is redirected to whatsapp, this information has to go along

Comment: You might be able to use cross-domain local storage but I'm not sure if it works with whats apps domain. how are you trying to process the data once you received it on whats up? I might be able to give you other alternatives.

Comment: @seriously sorry for the later response, I was without internet access.
So, I was told to refer the fields from the form (name, email and Phone)  and the fields from calculator (fees, amout of loan etc) in the whatsapp in this way: *Name of field. And I saw "this way" working from a guy's blog. I had no responde there in 2 months and I discovery this space and post my doubt here.

I dont know if a have to past the calculator field's in some variable and put this variables in the form using hidden fields or this way using * + filed's name works.

Comment: The thing I don't get is once you get the name, email, and phone number you want to send it to whats app right? Are you sending it to a what's app group or a specific phone number?

Comment: @seriously to a specific number.

Comment: I have update de post with the calculator post

Comment: can you point out the ids of the monthly fees and loan amount. The language is harder to understand.

Comment: and also by capture do you mean to send a png/jpeg version of the data or you just want to send the raw data as text to what app.

Comment: I'm sorry for the mess code, it's my first work with javascript. And a just want the raw data. I was able to send some data using GET instead POST in my form but I'm having trouble to retrive de raw data from the form url to "contato_enviar.php" wich is the file that redirects to whatsapp.

Comment: why do you need to send the data to PHP. Why don't you send it directly through javascript. Do you specifically need PHP?

Comment: So I managed to send almost all the fields to whatsapp, except the field with the value of the parcel, this field here (id=valparc)

<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <h4 class="title-form total-form">
          R$
          <span id="valparc">357,83</span>
          <span class="ast">*</span>
        </h4>
      </div>

my deadline is tomorrow and I decided so because it worked. but there's still a field missing. And I honestly have no idea how to take this value from this field and send it to the other page.

Comment: ```const parcel = document.getElementById('valparc').value``` then send ```parcel```